# Is there any way to assign a libname XSLX for SAS with a map?

Tags: sas, xlsx, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

In the past I've previously assigned libnames for XML or JSON engines with an associated map.
However, I cannot find any documentation regarding XSLX engines with maps.

An example for libname JSON engine I previously wrote is the following:

```
LIBNAME EFLOW JSON "&&WORKPATH/&&fichname" map="&JSONMAPS/**eflowjson.map**" ;
```

For an xlsx libname I only have ones without map, for instance:

```
libname _test xlsx "/FT/TI/RCP/teste1.xslx";
```

Being the map file a JSON file that forces attributes to have a certain pre-defined format.

With all of the above context, does anyone know a similar way for a libname XSLX?

Comment: No, XLSX files enforce no structure either so you cannot guarantee a file is in that format.

Comment: But for instance with proc import or infile you can force a format while reading it. 
Is it possible to do the same when assigning a libname?

Thanks

Comment: You can for text files, but not for Excel files. You can look into the DBSASTYPE option but it's not on the XLSX libname AFAIK.